# Populating a dataset depending on the values of a variable in another dataset

Tags: sas

I have two data sets INPUT and OUTPUT.

```
data INPUT;
  input 
    id 1-4 
    var1 $ 6-10 
    var2 $ 12-17 
    var3 $ 19-22
    transformation $ 24-26
  ;
datalines;
1023 apple banana oats 1:1 
1049 12    22      8   2x 
1219 milk  cream  fish 1:1 
;
run;
```

The OUTPUT dataset has a different structure. The variables do not have the same name.

```
data work.output;
attrib 
    variable_1  length=8 format=best12. label="Variable 1"
    variable_2 length=$50 format=$50. label="Variable 2"
    Variable_3 length=8 format=date9. label="Variable 3";
stop;
run;
```

OUTPUT will be filled with the values from input based on what is specified in column "transformation" in table INPUT: when "transformation" equals "1:1", I want to fill the OUTPUT ds with the values of the corresponding INPUT dataset. If this were a small excel, I would do copy & paste or a lookup.

For example, obs1 of dataset INPUT has transformation = 1:1, so I want to fill variable_1 of dataset OUTPUT with "apple", variable_2 with "banana" and variable_3 with "oats".
For the second observation of ds INPUT I want to multiply each variable with two and assign them to variable_1 - variable_3 respectively.

In my real dataset I have much more columns so I need to automate this, probalby via index, since the variable names do not correspond.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to code each transformation rule separately.

This works for your example.  But you did not include any date transformations so variable3 is not used.

```
data INPUT;
  input 
    id 1-4 
    var1 $ 6-10 
    var2 $ 12-17 
    var3 $ 19-22
    transformation $ 24-26
  ;
datalines;
1023 apple banana oats 1:1 
1049 12    22      8   2x 
1219 milk  cream  fish 1:1 
;

proc transpose data=input prefix=value out=step1;
  by id transformation;
  var var1-var3 ;
run;

data output;
  set step1;
  length variable1 8 variable2 $50 variable3 8;
  format variable3 date9.;
  if transformation='1:1' then variable2=value1;
  if transformation='2x' then variable1 = 2*input(value1,32.);
run;
```

Result

```
Obs     id     transformation    _NAME_    value1    variable1    variable2    variable3

 1     1023         1:1           var1     apple          .        apple               .
 2     1023         1:1           var2     banana         .        banana              .
 3     1023         1:1           var3     oats           .        oats                .
 4     1049         2x            var1     12            24                            .
 5     1049         2x            var2     22            44                            .
 6     1049         2x            var3     8             16                            .
 7     1219         1:1           var1     milk           .        milk                .
 8     1219         1:1           var2     cream          .        cream               .
 9     1219         1:1           var3     fish           .        fish                .
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand your example but when I tried to replicate it with real data I noticed that it did not work as intended. I tried using another example with data from the sas library:

data test;
set sashelp.cars;
run; 

proc transpose data = test out = test_t;
run;


However I noticed that proc transpose removed the columns MAKE, MODEL, TYPE, ORIGIN, DRIVE TRAIN, MSRP, INVOICE. Why is that?

Comment: If you do not use a VAR statement then PROC TRANSPOSE will use all of the numeric variables.  MAKE, MODEL etc are CHARACTER variables.  If you want to include them you need to list them in the VAR statement.